# Converting TIFF file and changing CRS

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geopandas, performance, rasterio, code-review

Is there a fastest way to:

1. Load a .tif file;
2. Convert it into GeoDataFrame; and
3. Change Coordinate Reference System?

I am using Python, and what I tried to do is:

1. Use rasterio to check if the Source CRS is equal to the Destination one.
2. After that the only way found to change the .tif file into a GeoPandasDataFrame
   was to use the GeoRasters library and apply the to_geopandas function.
3. In this way I was able to change the CRS using the to_crs function of GeoPandas.

Sample Code:

```
import rasterio as r
import georasters as gr
import geopandas as gpd


destinationCRS = "EPSG:4326"
sourceCRS = r.open(tif_file).crs.to_epsg()

geoFrame = gr.to_geopandas(gr.from_file(tif_file))

if sourceCRS != destinationCRS:
    geoFrame = geoFrame.to_crs(destinationCRS) 

return geoFrame
```

However, the problem is that this process is very slow, due to the high number of cells inside .tif file. (It take almost 25 minutes for 3 million cells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of geopandas for rasters is [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray) - geospatial xarray extension powered by rasterio.

To do what you want:
https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html

```py
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(tif_file)
rds_4326 = rds.rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")
rds_4326.rio.to_raster("file.tif")
```

If you want to add compression and tiling:

```py
rds_4326.rio.to_raster("file.tif", compress="DEFLATE", tiled=True)
```